# Aggregate two columns into one

Tags: react-admin

We have in a `List` view a `Datagrid` which among other fields uses two `ReferenceField` columns.

```
<List {...props}>
    <Datagrid>
        <ReferenceField reference="client-active" source="id" link="show" label="Client (active)">
            <ClientProfileSummary  />
        </ReferenceField>
        <ReferenceField reference="client-passive" source="id" link="show" label="Client (passive)">
            <ClientProfileSummary  />
        </ReferenceField>
    </Datagrid>
</List>
```

Now, each record either has one or the other reference, but never both. Is there a way so that we only have one column and take whichever value is present? Everything else is equal, it's just another resource.

Comment: I don't understand your model. You use a ReferenceField to reference the resource "client-active" or "client-passive" with the same id as the current table ? Not a different foreign key ?

Comment: Yes, same foreign key, because it is a partition. Either it is one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand properly, you have to create a component as below :

```js
import React, { useCallback } from 'react'
import { useReference, LinearProgress, ResourceContextProvider, ReferenceField } from 'react-admin'
import { get } from lodash
import ErrorIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Error'

const TwoFieldsToOneField = (props) => {
  const { label, children, source, activeClientReference, passiveClientReference, ...rest } = props
  const id = get(record, source)
  
  const activeClientState = useReference(activeClientReference, id);
  const passiveClientState = useReference(passiveClientReference, id);
  
  const error = activeClientState.error ? activeClientState.error : passiveClientState.error
  if (error) {
    return (
      <ErrorIcon
        aria-errormessage={error.message ? error.message : error}
        role="presentation"
        color="error"
        fontSize="small"
      />
    );
  }

  if (!activeClientState.loaded || !passiveClientState.loaded) {
    return <LinearProgress />
  }

  if (!activeClientState.data && !passiveClientState.data) {
    return null
  }

  let reference = ""
  if (activeClientRecord) {
    reference = "client-active"
  } else if (passiveClientRecord) {
    reference = "client-passive"
  }
  
  return (
    <ReferenceField reference={reference} source="id" link="show" label={label}>
      {children}
    </ReferenceField>
  )
}

...

<List {...props}>
    <Datagrid>
        <TwoFieldsToOneField activeClientReference="client-active" activeClientReference="client-passive" source="id" link="show" label="Active/Passive">
            <ClientProfileSummary  />
        </TwoFieldsToOneField >
    </Datagrid>
</List>
```

However it may not be the most optimal and send 2x one of the API calls.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It did not run directly, but it lead me to the correct path!